# Scala Regex: matching a non single character input

Tags: regex, scala

For instance the function:

```
val reg = "[^ ]".r
```

takes in an input that would match with every character except for the empty space character.

and:

```
def matchReg(line: String): List[String] = reg.findAllIn(line).toList
```

Converts the input into a list.

However how would I edit this so that it would match with a non-single character input. Since it seems as though  this splits the input such as "14" into "1" and "4" when the values of the regular expression are turned into a list. If the input is "14" I want it to output "14" rather than it being split. Thank you.

**EDIT: I have written test cases to explain the type of output I am looking for**

```
"The match" should "take list" in {
    assert(matchReg("(d e f)") == List("(", "d", "e", "f", ")"))
  }

  it should "take numbers" in {
    assert(matchReg("(12 45 -9 347 4)") == List("(", "12", "45", "-9", "347", "4", ")"))
  }

  it should "take operators" in {
    assert(matchReg("(- 7 (* 8 9))") == List("(", "-", "7", "(", "*", "8", "9", ")", ")"))
  }
```

With the following case, "take list" and "take operators" passes successfully if I use:

```
val reg = "[^ ]".r
```

However "take numbers" does not pass since numbers such as "347" are being split into "3" "4" and "7", when I want them to register as one single number.

Comment: Do you want to extract digit sequences? `"""\d+""".r.findAllIn(line).toList`?

Comment: @anubhava I have updated the question for better clarification

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please check the update I have made to clarify the question better

Comment: @jwvh if the input is "fed" then the output should be List("fed") but if the input was "fe" and "d" then the output should be List("fe","d")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you

```
val reg = """[^ \(\)]+|\(|\)""".r
```

You should add some other alternatives if you want to support also *[ ]* , *{ }* or other operators

```
@ matchReg("(d e f)") 
res8: List[String] = List("(", "d", "e", "f", ")")

@ matchReg("(12 45 -9 347 4)") 
res9: List[String] = List("(", "12", "45", "-9", "347", "4", ")")

@ matchReg("(- 7 (* 8 9))") 
res10: List[String] = List("(", "-", "7", "(", "*", "8", "9", ")", ")")
```

Comment: Thank you! this does work, could you just explain the parameters used if possible? as I am still getting to learn how they work.

Comment: I suggest you to use a website like https://regex101.com/ to test regular expression. Here, in the top-right corner, you will find also the explanation for each element of the reg exp